# Hibernate 4: no EntityMode.DOM4J? no dom4j export?

Tags: hibernate, dom4j

with hibernate 3 i was able to export xml data using a session with EntityMode.DOM4J:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
org.hibernate.Session dom4jSession = session.getSession(EntityMode.DOM4J);
...
```

today i tried hibernate 4. The package org.hibernate.classic is empty and there's no DOM4J in EntityMode anymore. i also tried setting the property "hibernate.default_entity_mode" to "dom4j", but this refers to the same error as above (Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class org.hibernate.EntityMode.DOM4J).

Is it still possible to use dom4j xml serialization with hibernate 4?
or am i missing something else?

thank you

Comment: seems i'm not the only one with this problem: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6879

Answer (score 0):

> That feature was always experimental and has been removed. I would like to get back to allowing such a thing, but it will more be allowing "marshallers" to be passed in. If you feel like working on that, contact the dev team on the hibernate-dev mailing list.

this feature was removed in hibernate 4. sadly, the documentation of hibernate 4 still describes this feature the way it was in hibernate 4.

is there an other way to have jpa and xml export/import without using additional jaxb annotations? maybe eclipselink has such a feature?